# Pandas filtering only month and day

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with a column `Date`:

```
2010-01-02 00:00:00
2010-03-05 00:00:00
2012-11-21 00:00:00
2013-05-16 00:00:00
.
.
.
2019-07-14 00:00:00
2019-09-19 00:00:00
```

And I would like to remain only the dates with specified months, regardless of the year. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain the month and day with [**`.dt.month`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [**`.dt.day`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) respectively. So you can filter with:

```
df[(df['Date'].dt.month == 3) & (df['Date'].dt.day == 5)]
```

to obtain the data that was generated on the fifth of march, for all years.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with filtering by [`Series.dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and 
[`Series.dt.day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day.html)
:

```
#if necessary
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df1 = df[(df['Date'].dt.month == 6) & (df['Date'].dt.day == 1)]
```

Or use [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then parentheses should be omitted:

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].dt.month.eq(6) & df['Date'].dt.day.eq(1)]
```